# Highlighting a range of cells based on days off. - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I already got some help with this before, and had it working.  Since, I have flipped the orientation of my schedule and instead of going across it is now going down.  And this conditional formatting no longer works.

```
=OR(LEFT(TEXT(B$5,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($L$2,2),LEFT(TEXT(B$5,"ddd"),2)=LEFT($M$2,2))
```

Where am I going wrong?  The days off are in text format.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following formula. Hope it works.

```
=OR(LEFT(TEXT($B5,"ddd"),3)=LEFT(TEXT($L$2,"DDDD"),3),LEFT(TEXT($B5,"ddd"),3)=LEFT(TEXT($M$2,"DDDD"),3))
```

Temporary working screen shot placed below.

[image: temporary working screenshot]